# Mostrar erro PHP no Atom

Tags: php, editor-de-texto, atom

Colegas.

Estou usando o editor Atom para desenvolvimento, já instalei alguns pacotes, porém percebi que o Atom não mostra erros de sintax. Alguém conhece algum pacote do Atom que faça esse serviço? Tentei usar o linter-php, porém aparece o erro abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por erros de programação você diz erros de sintaxe? Se sim, você pode utilizar o pacote [Linter PHP](https://atom.io/packages/linter-php).

Comment: Olá Anderson. Obrigado pela correção. Instalei o linter-php, porém dá o erro na imagem que coloquei no post.

Comment: Substitua `executablePath` por `/usr/bin/php`, ficando assim: `"linter-php": '/usr/bin/php'`

Comment: o erro sumiu. Perdoe-me a ignorância, mas '/usr/bin/php'  seria o diretório do PHP no meu computador ou deixo com essa nomenclatura mesmo?

Comment: É o caminho para onde o PHP está instalado na sua máquina.

Comment: Perfeito. Muito obrigado Anderson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Linter PHP seria uma boa solução, mas ele foi uma gambiarra temporária.
Graças ao [Nuclide](https://nuclide.io/), uma comunidade bem ativa e potente adotada pelo Facebook, agora o que era apenas um editor, acabouse transformando em uma verdadeira IDE.

Para fazer o seu Atom Editor se transformar em uma IDE oficial, é muito fácil. Vem comigo e siga os passos abaixo:

1. Instale o pacote [atom-ide-ui](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ide-ui)
2. Instale o seu pacote de linguagem favorita. Neste caso, o PHP: [ide-php](https://github.com/atom/ide-php/)

Eu escrevi um artigo fazendo um review e um comentário mais bacana da ferramenta. [Acesse este link para obter mais informações.](http://binariux.com.br/seja-bem-vindo-ao-atom-ide/)

Answer (score 2):

> Versão utilizada: Atom 1.14.4 x64. Alguns detalhes podem variar conforme a versão e configuração do editor, tal como idioma.

### Linter PHP

Para exibir erros de sintaxe, pode fazer uso do pacote [Linter PHP](https://atom.io/packages/linter-php).

Você precisará ter o PHP instalado na máquina. Após isso, basta instalar o pacote executando o comando:

```
apm install linter-php
```

Ou entrar em *Edit / Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl + Comma</kbd>), entrar na aba *Install*, buscando pelo nome **linter-php**. Pressione *Install*. Se necessário, permita adicionar todas as dependências do pacote.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dependendo da sua instalação do PHP, possivelmente você terá que configurar o caminho do executável para o pacote. Para isso, entre em `Edit / Config...` e adicione, se ainda não existir, o trecho:

```
'linter-php':
  # php path. run 'which php' to find the path 
  'executablePath': /usr/bin/php
```

Lembrando que `/usr/bin/php` deve ser o caminho para a instalação do PHP. Em ambientes Linux, geralmente será este caminho dado.

Feito isso, o pacote já deverá estar funcionando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]